# VB2010 Invert Scroll Bar Value

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have a vertical scroll bar on a form.
I would like the value of the scroll bar to be, from top to bottom, 35 to -35.

I tried to set the minimum value to 35 and max to -35, but vb wont allow it.

Is there a way to do this without catching the value when it's changed and storing the inverted value in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You will have to convert it yourself. Though you can make coding easier by having a property that calculates it automatically:

```
public int SliderValueTransformed
{
    get
    {
        return -this.Slider.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me? What do you mean? You **do** know what a property is, don't you? Oh, wait, this was tagged VB... and... not really VB.NET either, right? Umm... might have made a little mistake here... So.. which VB would this be, actually?